# Accessing values from blocking Javascript functions in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

The below function, `startScript`, contains blocking code that takes some time to run. In my `setInterval` loop, I want to access the `weight` value that it returns. However, when I run this Node program I receive an error saying that `new_weight` is undefined.

I tried running `startScript.on('close', ...)` within the loop, but this throws an error saying that there is no method `on` for `startScript`

What am I doing wrong here?

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
var path = require('path');
var split = require('split');
var pythonData = [];
var weight = null;

function startScript(){
  var pyScript = spawn('python', [ path.join(__dirname, 'script.py') ]);
  pyScript.stdout.on('data', function(lineChunk){
    pythonData = lineChunk.toString().replace(/[\S|\n|\[|\]]/,"").split(',');
  });

  pyScript.on('close', function(code){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=0; i < pythonData.length; i++){
      sum += parseFloat(pythonData[i]);
    }
    var weight = sum / pythonData.length;
    console.log("weight: " + weight);
    return weight;
  });
}

setInterval(function(){
  if (some event that occurs infrequently){
    startScript();
    var new_weight = weight + 100
    console.log(new_weight);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: you never defined `weight`. and you never accepted a return value from start script.

Comment: I mean this in the nicest way possible but this example makes absolutely no sense. I'm assuming you've tried to abstract out a simple idea from a larger body of code. Is there any way you could give us the real code?

Comment: Ok, you defined weight, but you never gave it a value.

Comment: It's still just `null`. if `startScript` is giving `weight` a value, then you would be able to access it the way you are. http://jsfiddle.net/86z3Z/

Comment: You realise you're running startScript every second, right?

Comment: `startScript` kicks off an external python script, which takes some time to run. What I think is happening, is the script is kicked off and `new_weight` is being assigned the null value before `startScript` has time to finish

Comment: That makes sense, but the only way (realistically) to solve that is through callbacks. (which has to be built-into startScript, it's not something that's already done for you)

Comment: I'm checking to see if a door sensor has opened up, so I need to poll the sensor reguarly

Comment: we need to see more of startScript. if startScript is asynchronous (which i believe to be the case given what you've said thus far) it can't return the value and you must use callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant' return from `pyScript.on()`, it's asynchronous. The parent function has returned already long before the other return happens. Instead, you must use callbacks.

```
function startScript(callback){ // ******
  var pyScript = spawn('python', [ path.join(__dirname, 'script.py') ]);
  pyScript.stdout.on('data', function(lineChunk){
    pythonData = lineChunk.toString().replace(/[\S|\n|\[|\]]/,"").split(',');
  });

  pyScript.on('close', function(code){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=0; i < pythonData.length; i++){
      sum += parseFloat(pythonData[i]);
    }
    var weight = sum / pythonData.length;
    console.log("weight: " + weight);
    //return weight; // you can't return weight. Instead, execute the callback.
    callback(weight); // ******
  });
}

setInterval(function(){
  if (some event that occurs infrequently){
    startScript(function(weight){ // ******
      var new_weight = weight + 100
      console.log(new_weight);
    }); // ******
  }
}, 1000);
```